# Jenkins(Windows ) unable to clone through git(Linux) repository

Tags: windows, git, jenkins

**Set-up Details:**

JENKINS on windows 10

GIT plugin setup done

public private key setup done

**Cloning repository through CMD works**
[image: Cloning repository through CMD works]

**git clone through Jenkins fails with below error**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Aclselenium>git clone rahulp@10.0.6.194:/Operations/repo/git/test.git 
Cloning into 'test'...
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."
```

[image: JENKINS Console Logs]

Running below commands through windows cmd

```
"whoami" command gives > "acl-wireless\rahulp"

"echo %USERNAME%" command gives `> "rahulp"`
```

Where as when I run above command through JENKINS I receive:

```
"whoami" command gives > "nt authority\system"

"echo %USERNAME%" command gives `> "RAHULPANDEY$ RAHULPANDEY$"`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command line access to `git` and your `jenkins` access to `git` are two different things. From command line, you will be given your `username` and `password` to login. But from `jenkins` you need to configure credentials. Go to `Manage Jenkins` => `Configure System` => `GitHub` and please give the credentials there.